# Weird characters in JavaFX Labels

Tags: java, javafx

Good afternoon.
I'm having some problems with JavaFX, basically I create my Labels by code (I'm using IntelliJ IDE):

Calls from the Card object (Object containing the Label):

```
   vibrationCard = new Card("METRICA", "Eixos de vibração", "");
   fftCard = new Card("METRICA", "FFT", "");
```

Object Card (Object that contains the Label)

```
    public Card(String topLabel, String title, String bottomLabel){
    
            cardTitleLabel = new Label(title);
            cardTitleLabel.setFont(new Font(14.0));
    
    //Code remainder
            cardStruct.getChildren().addAll(
                    cardTopLabel,
                    cardTitleHeaderHBox,
                    separator,
                    contentAnchorPane,
                    cardBottomLabel
            );
    
            getChildren().addAll(cardStruct);
        }
```

The problem is, my labels have strange characters where they should be accented letters:

[image: Exemple 1]

[image: Example 2]

I've already set the IDE to UTF-8 and I've also tried converting the formatting of the string to see if I could fix it, but it didn't work.

[image: Example 3]

Comment: `cardTitleLabel = new Label(title)` says what?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with a simple `new Label("Eixos de vibração")`. I don't understand why you have that convert-to-utf8-bytes-then-back-to-a-string bit in your code. What do you expect that to do? Because all that _will_ do is give you back a string with the exact same sequence of characters as you had before.

Comment: Your native file encoding might *not* be UTF-8

Comment: Are you sure that `-encoding utf-8` is being specified when your code is compiled?

Comment: How would I format the file?

Comment: Open the file at a Portuguese diacritics line in a binary editor and see what it says

Comment: My guess, something like `0000001c: 2245 6978 6f73 2064 6520 7669 6272 61e7 e36f 2229 3b0a                           "Eixos de vibra..o");`

Comment: Apparently using Unicode CSS code in place of the special characters worked, but I don't know how to do it for full texts.

Comment: Shouldn't need to. You really need to get rid of the mismatch such that the code I posted will work

Comment: What version of Java is it?  [Java defaults to UTF-8 since Java 18](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400), just as an FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

You must make sure that

1. The Java source files in your editor are saved using UTF-8
2. The Compiler does read them using UTF-8

If you use Maven, add this to your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

If you use Gradle, add this to your build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {options.encoding = 'UTF-8'}
```

**Additional notes:**

Converting from and back UTF-8 is tricky sometimes. As last resort, delete the file, rewrite its content with copy Paste and rewrite the Strings MANUALLY WITH YOUR KEYBOARD NOT WITH COPY PASTE, because the characters theirself can be in the wrong format. This can happen too by copy pasting characters from the internet or from third Party documents into a String.